# Function within function to compare with current date (Excel)

Tags: excel, comparison, date-comparison

I have a column with various dates and want to check if the date is equal or after the 1st January of the current year. I use the following code to get the 1st January of the current year.

```
="01.01."&YEAR(TODAY())
```

How would I insert this into a formula to check if the date in cell B3 is equal or after the given date? The following is not working

```
=IF(B3>=""01.01."&YEAR(TODAY())";True;False)
```

Comment: Did my answer work for you? If so then please mark as correct by clicking the grey/green check mark by the answer. It is something only you can do.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
=B3>=DATE(YEAR(TODAY());1;1)
```

This will return TRUE or FALSE.  No need for the IF() statement if all you want is a TRUE/FALSE.